# why can't I create cookies in Firefox?

Tags: php, firefox, cookies

I am not able to create a Firefox cookie with following line:

```
    setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/", "localhost");
```

Does someone know why?

I have checked the settings in FF and it accepts cookies from 3rd parties and are deleted when they expire.

EDIT: I can create now with this line:

```
$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;
setcookie('cookiename', 'data', time()+60*60*24*365, '/', $domain, false);
```

but how do I delete it?

I tried with just switching the + to - but it didn't work.

```
$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;
setcookie('cookiename', 'data', time()-60*60*24*365, '/', $domain, false);
```

Comment: Is "/" a valid path?
Have you tried "/foo/"?

Comment: Just to clarify... to access the site to test, you're typing http://localhost into the address bar?  Just want to make sure you're not using like http://127.0.0.1 or http://192.168.1.xx or something similar.

Comment: valid path of? i dont quite understand what location path starts from.

my webroot it in localhost/projects/blinder and the file calling it is index.php. what should the path and domain be set to?

Comment: yes im using localhost/projects/blinder/index.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been awhile since I worked with localhost cookies, but according to the comments in the PHP manual, 'localhost' is an invalid value for the domain parameter.

To set a cookie on localhost, use `false` instead.  Example:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/", false);
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#73107

Comment: thank you it worked. but now the problem is how do i delete it?
 see my updated version

Comment: To delete a cookie, you should set the expiration date to be in the past.  In your case you'd use `setcookie("TestCookie", '', time()-3600, "/", false);`