# only Firefox php cookie issue

Tags: php, firefox, cookies

I have problem with cookie only in firefox

This is what I have in .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

In my index.php:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['SplashScreen']))
{
  setcookie('SplashScreen', '1',  time()+60*60*24*30,'/');
  header("Location: splash.html");
}
```

In my splash.html I have:

```
<area href="/index.php" coords="944,354,950,354,954,352,957,349,962,347,963,351,961,356,960,360,962,365,967,370,968,375,972,379,977,381,983,383,990,385,996,385,1002,385,1008,384,1010,381,1013,379,1017,377,1021,383,1020,387,1017,392,1013,399,1011,402,1008,401,1008,399,1008,395,1006,392,1003,390,1001,390,998,389,997,392,997,396,998,400,995,403,992,404,990,407,988,410,985,413,983,415,981,417,979,419,977,421,974,424,971,426,967,429,965,434,966,439,965,443,964,446,964,450,961,452,958,455,956,458,952,457,950,451,949,447,947,443,944,438,943,433,941,429,939,424,938,419,939,414,939,409,938,404,936,403,934,407,931,409,926,407,924,403,927,401,921,397,923,394,929,395,930,392,928,387,926,384,928,381,934,379,938,375,943,372,946,367,947,362,946,358" shape="poly">
```

In firefox the cookie is created but stays in same splash.html, where as other browsers redirect to index.php when we click on the area.

All other browser supoorts the logic except firefox.

Comment: where is the image and map do you have those properly written?

Comment: Explore error log. Also check headers by browser.

Comment: You should have `<map name="map_name">` and `<img src="img.png" usemap="#map_name">`.

Comment: Try debugging the content of `$_COOKIE` for FireFox, compared to other browsers (e.g. with `echo var_dump( $_COOKIE ); exit();`.

Comment: I have image tag and map tag, i don't see any issue there.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I'm getting a black output there it means $_COOKIE is black, but firebug shows me the cookie

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211822/php-cookies-problem-works-in-firefox-not-in-other-browser?rq=1). [Another possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877984/why-cant-i-create-cookies-in-firefox).

Comment: Both did not worked for me