# prestashop `$this->context->cookie ` not work in firefox

Tags: php, cookies, prestashop

I'm developing payment option module for my prestashop project.what i'm trying to do is ;
after user select payment option and complete the order,set some values in to cookie.those values tried to get when `hookDisplayOrderConfirmation` hook trigger.it's work fine in chrome.but not in firefox

**set cookie**

```
protected function getInsurance()
{
   if((empty($_GET['epf']))||(empty($_GET['company']))) {
       $msg="Invalid parameters";
       $this->errorAction($msg);
   }else{
       $this->context->cookie->__set("company",$_GET['company']);
       $this->context->cookie->__set("epf",$_GET['epf']);

       error_log("cookie set  ".$this->context->cookie->company);
   }
}
```

**get cookie**

```
public function hookDisplayOrderConfirmation($params)
{
   error_log("cookie get  ".$this->context->cookie->company);
}
```

**error_log**

in Chrome

[image]

in firefor

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877984/why-cant-i-create-cookies-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

I came across with a similar problem and I ended up setting cookie value directly:

SET

```
setcookie("company", $_GET['company']);
```

GET

```
$_COOKIE["company"]
```

Comment: Having this problem as well right now, in PS 1.6.10 the cookie seems to be encrypted, so $_COOKIE only contains a string of random characters.